# Google Apps Script to search Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

Is it possible to use Google Apps Script to search Google Drive for both documents and folders?

Google have killed their own docs/drive search gadget as it appears to rely on iGoogle and Google Enterprise support have admitted this.

Thank you

Comment: It is indeed possible... it is also possible to show your attempts.... or not.?  Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are looking for [SearchFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles%28String%29) and [SearchFolder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFolders%28String%29) of the DriveApp.
The full list of parameters is available in the [Google Drive SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters)

I've run some tests and seems like it's not possible to do 1 search and get files and folders like it's possible calling the search function from the Google Drive API.

Here a code that list the files and folders with a title that have 2013 in it

```
function myFunction() {
  var searchFor ='title contains "2013"';
  var names =[];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    names.push(file.getName());
  }
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders(searchFor);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var file = folders.next();
    names.push(file.getName());
  }
  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    Logger.log(names[i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you smokybob, I think you are correct and thanks for the code snippet.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Please remember to mark reply as Answer so that anyone with a similar problem can find it

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code

```
function searchDrive() {
  var folderToSearch = "FolderName";
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderToSearch);
  Logger.log(folders);

  var fileToSearch = "fileName";
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileToSearch);
  Logger.log(files);
}
```

This example can be found [here](https://script.google.com/d/1if6-1K0FaRMCtAGcMauwZkdKO9W-Uqr-Vb7bsORgCPomooYHeoQkJW_k/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: That is not what he is asking. Your code only finds items with the exact name, its not searching. Gas does have search though but the asker hasnt even tried to search the gas documentation so I wont either.

Comment: Thank you br araujo. And Zig you are partially correct, I have checked the GAS documentation but I'm outta my depth here. I naively thought it would be trivial to search (Google) Drive from a (Google) Site within a domain.