# Script for Search in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script

I have a script that should search all the files in Google drive. I implemented the script into one of Google sites page. The script works only for the files that are in root folder but doesn't work for the files that are in sub-folders. Any help appreciated. Thank you

Here is the current script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var results = DriveApp.getFolderById('yourGoogleDriveId').searchFiles('fullText contains "' + e.parameter.q + '"');
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Results: <br /><br /><ul>');
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var file = results.next();
    output.append('<li><a href="' + file.getUrl() + '">' + file.getName() + '</a></li>');
  }
  output.append('</ul>');
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it directly without the "getFolderById", otherwise it look for files under that particular folder? i.e. var results = DriveApp.searchFiles('fullText contains "' + e.parameter.q + '"');

Comment: Yes, even though I knew that it is not going to work but I have tried your suggestion. It doesn't know where to look for files without Drive folder ID#.

Comment: Also all the files are in the subfolder of the root folder and I typed root folder ID# into script. It should search for all the files/folders under the root.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722229/google-apps-script-to-search-google-drive) if it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

As @Cesar mentioned, `DriveApp.getFolderById().searchFiles()` should be `DriveApp.searchFiles()`. Two class `DriveApp` and `Folder` both have `searchFiles()` method, but only the former searches recursively. Read the documentations.

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchFiles(String)

I copied your code and tested it (with `modifedDate` to speed up) and it went fine.

Comment: I know that the code will run if only you are doing for Google drive that in the same account with Google site. But I am trying to pull files from a Google drive that is not related to same account that Google site built in. Hope that clears.

Comment: Then, according to API documentations, you have no built-in function available for sub-folders.